# One BLoC per feature or per use case?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm trying to create an app using BLoC architecture.
I separated out features (like settings, sign in, sign up etc.) and now I need to design my BLoCs.

What is the proper way of doing it? Should I create one BLoC per feature or one per use case?
For instance settings. User can change password, avatar and manage notifications preferences.
Should I create `SettingsBloc` with events (and states) coresponding to possible interactions? Or better way is to create `ChangePasswordBloc`, `ChangeAvatarBloc` and use `MultiBlocBuilder`?

I tried to implement first approach but I do not know how to rebuild only one part of UI, how to filter proper state.

Answer (score 6):

I would say per feature. Bloc has some pretty nice documentation (docs and sample apps).

My recommendation is to have a look [here](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertodostutorial?id=architecture)

The link points to the demo **Todo app** where you can read about about how the application was structured and why.

Answer (score 0):

i think its better to have Bloc for every feature but it's not a fixed rule and it depends on situation . my way of thinking  is like  have a AuthBLoc or UserBLoc wich  implement usecases like signIn or signUp ,  or for settings i Usually have a ThemeBloc wich has Theming operations.

as for your second statement you usually have different states for different events and usecases for example you would have UserSignInState and UserSignUpState and in your BlocBuilder you check if coming state is a UserSignUpState and if it was you return your UI .